# Doing a post request to a spring 2.0 controller

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, post, controller

I have a form on an html page like this:

```
<form id="profileForm" method="post" action="myapp/profile/save.do">
    <input type="text" name="profileList[0].name" value="Jane"/>
    <input type="text" name="profileList[1].name" value="John"/>
    <input type="text" name="profileList[2].name" value="Alice"/>
</form>
```

When I submit this form, A post request is send to the spring dispatcher servlet, which calls my controller:

```
public class Save extends SimpleFormController
{
    @Override
    protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
    {
        //This method runs fine.

        ProfileFbo ProfileFbo = new ProfileFbo();

        return ProfileFbo;
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception
    {
        //This method doesn't run

        Map<String, Object> modelData = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        return showForm(request, response, errors, modelData);
    }
}
```

The first method runs, the second doesn't. Something must go wrong with binding the submitted data to my fbo? Here's my fbo, which is nothing but a container for a list of profileDto objects:

```
public class ProfileFbo
{
    private List<ProfileDto> profileList;

    public List<ProfileDto> getProfileList()
    {
        return profileList;
    }

    public void setProfileList(List<ProfileDto> profileList)
    {
        this.profileList = profileList;
    }
}
```

and of course, the profileDto object has a property called "name" and an appriopate getter/setter.

Here's my spring.xml configuration:

```
<bean id="profileSaveController" class="com.company.profile.controller.Save">
    <property name="successView" value="profileOverviewPageTile"/>
    <property name="commandName" value="profileFbo"/>
    <property name="commandClass" value="com.company.profile.fbo.ProfileFbo"/>
</bean>
```

As you can see, I'm not using this controller to do GET request, so I'm not really ùmaking full use of the spring form controller functionality. this is purely for doing POSt requests and binding the form to the fbo object.

What am I doing wrong in this setup?

Comment: Please post the spring configuration

Comment: @RobertMoskal oops, the text between "<" ">" got hidden automatically

Answer (score 0):

Wow, that's old school!

I don't see where the myapp/profile/save.do endpoint you are calling in your html is defined.

You really should be using the spring jsp tags for this:

```
<form:form method="POST"commandName="profileFbo">
```

That should hit the correct backend endpoint.

You know you shouldn't be handling forms like this anymore, right?

Comment: We're stuck with a legacy java 1.5 / spring 2.0 application. Either way, the  mapping to the controller is NOT the problem, because the controller does run. It's just the onsubmit that isn't running. I looked at the form:form tag, but it just renders as plain old form html object so I don't see the added value of using the tag? I think there's a problem with the binding between my reqyest body and the fbo/list of profiles.

Comment: So the myapp/profile/save.do endpoint is what' would be generated by the tag?

Comment: Yes, I use "<c:url />" for this url. The request comes in my controller with correct request body, but the binding of the request body to the profile fbo object doesn't occur properly.

Comment: Ah so the method runs. I misunderstood from your question. I thought you were getting no routing. You may want to amend your question.